# How to surround individual text with markup using join in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made this function that each time a user checks a checkbox, the value from that gets pushed into an array and then it's value is displayed in a div called "selections". For each successive check, this gets joined as text in that display.

My question is, how can I surround each text value that is displayed within `<span>` or `<div>`? My current example does it for the first entry value but not the others..

So it currently looks like this when running:

```
<span>cbExample1</span>"cbExample2cbEample3"
```

The first example is fine but I'd like to surround "cbExample2" and "cbExample3" with  tags.

Code is below:

```
    var selections = [],
    render_selections = 
      function() {               
        $('.selections').html("<span>"+selections.join('</span>'));
      }

     $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
       $(this).each(function() {
         var maxAllowed = 3;
         var cnt = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;  
         if (cnt <= maxAllowed) {
           $('.selCount .counter').html(selReset-cnt);
           selections = $.map($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'), function(a) { return a.value; });
           render_selections();
           console.log(selections); 

         } else if (cnt > maxAllowed) {
           $(this).prop("checked", "");
           $(this).unbind("click");
           $(this).css("cursor","default");

         }
       });
     });
```

Comment: You want to join them with a closing tag followed by the next opening tag … and then put an opening tag in front and a closing tag on the back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:

```
selections = ['a','b','c'];
```

This line:

```
$('.selections').html("<span>"+selections.join('</span>'));
```

will produce: `<span>a</span>b</span>c`

If you change that line to this:

```
$('.selections').html("<span>"+selections.join('</span><span>')+"</span>");
```

You will get what you want: `<span>a</span><span>b</span><span>c</span>`